# Can I assign individual character to a string in c++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program to reverse a string. I used the following code but unfortunately it didn't work. I am a little confused why that happened.

Here is my code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string InputString = "Hello";
    string OutputString;
    int length;

    length = InputString.length();

    for (int i=length-1, j=0; i >=0, j<length; i--, j++)
        OutputString[j] = InputString[i]; 

    cout << "The reverse string of " << InputString << " is "
         << OutputString << ".\n";

    return 0;
}
```

My output is:
The reverse string of Hello is .

Comment: OutputString[j] ??

Comment: I would also *strongly* recommend writing `const int length = InputString.length();` get in the habit of using `const` as often as possible.  It makes a lot of bugs easier to see, and compilers can like it for optimizing.

Comment: Finally, using `size_t` for `length`, `i` and j` is a good habit to get into.  Containers tend to use `size_t` for their length and index variables.  It saves a lot of hassle in the long run if you follow the same style.

Comment: Worth mentioning you could also do `OutputString = InputString; std::reverse(OutputString.begin(), OutputString.end();`

Comment: With both `i` and `j` in the loop control, the code is very confusing. You can eliminate either one by expressing it in terms of the other, since `i` is always `length - 1 - j` in the current code. And note that `i >= 0, j < length` in the loop test is the same as writing `j < length`; to test both conditions, change it to `i >= 0 && j < length`.

Answer (score 7):

The problem isn't quite what you think it is. It is that `OutputString` is *empty* and any indexing into it will be out of bounds and lead to *undefined behavior*.

You might instead do something like

```
OutputString += InputString[i];
```

to append characters to the string.

Also, the loop condition `i >=0, j<length` will not work like you think either. You are using the *comma expression* so while both `i >= 0` and `j<length` will be evaluated, only the result of `j<length` will be used. You probably want to use the logical and operator there: `i >=0 && j<length`.

Comment: I think `j<length` is OK by itself. Its meaning is the same as `i>=0` - so either condition is good. Evaluating both conditions does no harm (i.e. harms only the programmer's brain)

Comment: You could also do `OutputString.resize(length);` before the loop, and then keep your original loop.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to reverse strings like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc,char** argv){

    std::string hello = "hello";

    for(std::size_t i=0;i < hello.length()/2; ++i)
    {
        std::swap(hello[i],hello[hello.length()-i-1]);
    }

    std::cout<<hello<<std::endl;

 return 0;   
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/875d2365872c186bhttp://)

Comment: *Really*?  I prefer to use `std::reverse` myself - but that's not what the OP is asking about.  He is obviously learning the basics of C++.

Comment: What I meant was that reversing a string this way was what I was taught as an alternative to doing a reversal using the method that the OP is using. I had completely forgotten about `std::reverse`, thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

Or you simply do:

```
string OutputString(InputString.rbegin(), InputString.rend());
cout << "The reverse string of " << InputString << " is "
         << OutputString << ".\n";
```